# R parallelize a for loop when reading data from a list

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I have a for loop that I would like to run in parallel with `R`. The following loop goes through each product in a database by using the `index m` (I have a total of M products to price). 
I pass as input for my pricing function the original price (this is a numeric) and a discount rate that is read from a list (so I have to extract this value by using the `[[]] formulation`.

```
for(m in 1:M)
{ 
  myList[paste0("Product", m)] <- list(priceProduct(originalPrice, discounts[[m]])) 
}
```

This loop works fine and at the end I have the list `myList` contains the correct discounted prices for each product. myList has all the elements named `ProductX` where X is the product position in my original database (which in the loop is the counter m).
The only problem is that it is terribly slow to run so I was wondering how to parallelize this. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps `foreach` package is of use: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Vectorize your code first before you worry about parallel processing. R code is usually vectorized, but parallel processing is still more work to run. The `foreach` and `Rcpp` (if you know C++) packages can also make things even zippier. Or you can try your luck with Julia, which is fast, though not as mature. For most day-to-day work, though, vectorization does the trick.

The answer to your question depends a little on the specifics of how your data and functions are structured. The following makes some loose assumptions, but you should be able to adapt it to your particulars. (Or just add more details, and I'll come back and edit.)

```
# Let's say:
m <- 100

# `paste` functions can accept a sequence, and are easy to vectorize
product <- paste0("Product", 1:m)

# Let's chuck everything in a `data.frame` to stay organized:
data <- data.frame(product, originalPrice, discount)

# If `priceProduct` accepts vector arguments:
data$salePrice <- priceProduct(data$originalPrice, data$discount)

# If not:
data$salePrice <- sapply(seq(1, nrow(data)), function(x){
    priceProduct(data$originalPrice[x], data$discounts[x])
})

# If it spits out a list, more cleaning is in order:
data$salePrice <- do.call(c, 
    sapply(seq(1, nrow(data)), function(x){
        priceProduct(data$originalPrice[x], data$discounts[x])
}))
```